# Is assigning de-referenced character pointers really impossible?

Tags: c++, character, variable-assignment, dereference

So I think I may have read that I absolutely have to use `strncpy()` and that assigning a `char*` by dereference is just not possible. I tried it and had some trouble. Am I doing it wrong? Or is strncpy really the only way?

I wrote some code but found my character was not getting saved.

```
char* characterDestination = new char [ 50 ];
*characterDestination = 'H';
characterDestination++;
cout << "Result: " << characterDestination << endl;


char characterDestination2[ 50 ];
strncpy( characterDestination2, "H", 1 );
cout << "Result: " << characterDestination2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
Result: 
Result: H
```

But I expected the `H` to print in both cases.

Comment: Why did you expect `H` to be printed?  Even though an answer was given, I'm curious as to what led you believe that `H` should be printed in the first example.  Bad C++ books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you have increased the pointer, which now points to the next element, not the one that you saved the 'H'.

Therefore, the `cout` that prints it, does not print the 'H', but whatever string exists in the memory after the first one and up to the \0 it finds. It printed nothing just because in your case, it happened that the \0 was the very next byte.

Both arrays are pointers, the difference is the first is dynamically allocated, where the second is static.  `characterDestination` and `characterDestination2` are both pointers.

Suggestion: forget all such stuff and string.h functions *completely* and use std::string.

Comment: Also note that in the first example, the pointer no longer points to the address returned by `new[]`, thus issuing a `delete[]` call on that pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: What minimal change would the first example require to see the printed H? I need to progress the pointer for the next element, but can I jump back somehow after printing the text?

Comment: print the character *before* advancing the pointer, and, really, go for a good c++ book.

Comment: Of course, just as `++` advances the pointer `--` moves the pointer back. You can go backward and forwards as many times as you like provided you stay within the bounds of the array.